# preg_match_all() creates multiple empty arrays and one with match. How to retrieve the right one?

Tags: php, arrays, regex

**Using PHP 8.0.**

I want to search a line for regex matches and replace all those matches with a string. Here is the code I wrote to find matches:

```php
// $lines is an array of html document lines
function include_files(array $lines): array {
    $pattern = '/{FILE="[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+\.[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+"}/';
    foreach ($lines as $line){
        preg_match_all($pattern, $line, $matches);
        var_dump($matches);
        foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
            $file_name = get_block_file($match[0]);
            $file_content = file_get_contents($file_name);
            $line = str_replace($match[0], $file_content, $line);
        }
    }
    return $lines;
}
```

The problem is that `var_dump($matches)` displays the following:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(0) { } } 
array(1) { [0]=> array(0) { } } 
array(1) { [0]=> array(0) { } } 
array(1) { [0]=> array(0) { } } 
array(1) { [0]=> array(0) { } } 
array(1) { [0]=> array(0) { } } 
array(1) { [0]=> array(0) { } } 
array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "{FILE="1.txt"" } } 
array(1) { [0]=> array(0) { } } 
array(1) { [0]=> array(0) { } }
```

One of these arrays contains what I need, but neither can I accesses it nor can I understand where do all these other arrays come from. How can I fix this behavior?

Comment: Could we have access to the `$line` variable? It'll be easier to answer if the input of the regex match was available. Understand if it's sensitive input a similar example input would be appreciated. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`preg_replace` and `preg_replace_callback` can take an array as the subject, so you don't need the loop or multiple replaces.  You didn't supply any sample data for `$lines` so assuming your pattern works as needed:

```
$pattern = '/{FILE="[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+\.[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+"}/';
$lines   = preg_replace_callback($pattern,
                                 function($m) {
                                      return file_get_contents(get_block_file($m[0]));
                                 }, $lines);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is related with **$matches** variable, because this variable is inserted by reference **&$matches** and "n" iterations are being inserted.

```
preg_match_all ( string $pattern , string $subject , array &$matches = null , int $flags = 0 , int $offset = 0 ) : int|false|null
```

A possible solution would be to initialise the variable to null before calling the function **preg_match_all**

Example:

```
$pattern = '/{FILE="[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+\.[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+"}/';
foreach ($lines as $line){
    $matches = null;
    preg_match_all($pattern, $line, $matches);
```

I have not been able to test it, but I think it can be a quick solution.